# Syntax error on token "}", delete this token on gwt cache.html files after compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, myeclipse

I am a java developer and I have a very low background on html/javascript technologies, that is why i have chosen gwt for developing my web app.

When i compile my code using the google compiler inside myeclipse it says that everything went ok but then it starts to validate my project and starts to give

```
Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

Error.

Obviously i can just delete that character from the cache.html files but i dont know if this is a symptom of another, more important, issue?

Sometimes the deployed webapp doesn't react as it is supposed and I dont know if it is correlated with that error.

Any light on this? thank you.

...and sorry about my english and if this is a silly question.

**Update**

The file is a generated one, not written by me and is a really big file but the line where the error is:

```
function rpd(a){return function(){this.__gwt_resolve=spd;return a.xi()}}function rpd(a){return function(){this.__gwt_resolve=spd;return a.xi()}}
```

Expanding it

```
function rpd(a){
    return function(){
        this.__gwt_resolve=spd;
        return a.xi()
    }
}
function rpd(a){
    return function(){
        this.__gwt_resolve=spd;
        return a.xi()
    }
```

}

The only thing i notice is that it defines the same function twice and that the return statement doesnt have a ;. Dont know why gwt compiler spits that.

Comment: It's not necessarily a silly question, but it's hard to give any valid answer if you don't give the appropriate code.

Comment: Let me update the question.

Comment: Tell eclipse to exclude output directories from validation?

Comment: And can you post your java code that generates that javascript?

Comment: Thanks Uncle Iroh that is useful but regarding to my question it doesn't tell us if that error is a symptom of another major issue. Thanks btw :)

Comment: Mmm i don't know what is the specific java code that generates that javascript code. Its a big project with so many java classes that its hard to tell. The java code does not have errors. Note also that it is an example because i have the same error in several generated files.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess I've never tried to validate the generated javascript...I've just kinda trusted it.  Hopefully someone else has run into the issue you're mentioning and can offer their insight.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously a bug that GWT generates those two exact same functions, but it's not a JS error: the second will simply overwrite the first.

Semi-colons are also optional in JS in certain conditions (specifically before a closing brace; semicolons are separators in JS).

The bug you're seeing in your app is thus unrelated to these (check your browser dev tools for errors)